# Is it possible in scala to pass on a generic type dynamically?

Tags: scala, types

I  want to model arithmetic operations for the sake of writing a DSL.

A multiply operation on an `Int` and a `Double` should obviously lead to a `Double`, on an `Int` and a `Int` it should lead to an Int and so on.

Is there any way in scala to decide a type and pass it on dynamically? In below code I added, as a way of demonstration the function call `arithmeticReturnType(TL,TR)` which should then be replaced with something that would actually work in Scala.

```
trait NumericCol[Repr]

case class Divide[R](l: NumericCol[_], r: NumericCol[_]) extends NumericCol[R]

def divide[TL,TR](left: NumericCol[TL], right: NumericCol[TR]) = Divide[**arithmeticReturnType(TL,TR)**](left, right)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you ever looked into how scala collections are implemented, you probably have noticed all the "CanBuildFrom"-thingies that are used to determine the most specific return type for operations on collections. You can apply the same trick to ensure type safety in your DSL:

```
trait CanDivideInto[A, B, C] {
  def divide(a: A, b: B): C
}

implicit object DoubleIntCanDivideIntoDouble 
extends CanDivideInto[Double, Int, Double] {
  def divide(a: Double, b: Int): Double = a / b
}

implicit object InIntCanDivideIntoInt
extends CanDivideInto[Int, Int, Int] {
  def divide(a: Int, b: Int): Int = a / b
}

trait NumericCol[Repr]

case class Divide[A, B, C](
  l: NumericCol[A], 
  r: NumericCol[B], 
  divider: CanDivideInto[A, B, C]
) extends NumericCol[C]

def divide[A, B, C](
  left: NumericCol[A], 
  right: NumericCol[B]
)(implicit div: CanDivideInto[A, B, C]): NumericCol[C] = 
  Divide[A, B, C](left, right, div)

val a = new NumericCol[Double]{}
val b = new NumericCol[Int]{}

val c: NumericCol[Double] = divide(a, b)
// val nope: NumericCol[Int] = divide(a, b) // won't compile, good.
```

The different cases like `Int/Double`, `Double/Int`, `Int/Int` etc. might lead to some boilerplate, but I don't see any way around it, because dividing integers by doubles or integers by floats or integers by integers *should* result in different assembly instructions in the end of the day...

Comment: Brilliant! Introduce a Typeclass to bind types to their return type.. Im going to try to apply this and see if it fits all my usecases

Comment: My final result:
https://github.com/crobox/clickhouse-scala-client/blob/feature/voc-typed-magnets/dsl/src/main/scala/com.crobox.clickhouse/dsl/column/ArithmeticFunctions.scala

It works perfectly. Thanks once again.

Answer (score -1):

Type classes is one possibility, but in this case I don't see why not just use function overloads. It does the job, and saves a bunch of boilerplate:

```
def divide(a: NumericColumn[Int], b: NumericColumn[Int]) = Divide[Int](a,b)
def divide(a: NumericColumn[Double], b: NumericColumn[Double]) = Divide[Double](a,b)
```

(I think, these two is all you need to cover the divide case)

Comment: I have many many things that I need to be able to execute arithmetic operations on. Overloading is not an option.

I have about 10 arithmetic operations, 10 types that each need to be compatible with eachother, on the left end and the right end. so that will be 10 X 10 x 10 = 1000 functions.

Comment: Well, 1000 type classes sounds even crazier :) 
The point is that overloading is _less_ boilerplate than type classes.

Comment: I think you don't fully understand the solution @AndreyTyukin is offering. I suggest you take a look at my code here (I already implemented his solution): 
https://github.com/crobox/clickhouse-scala-client/blob/feature/voc-typed-magnets/dsl/src/main/scala/com.crobox.clickhouse/dsl/column/ArithmeticFunctions.scala

As you can see the typeclasses are universal. They can be used by any method wich needs to find out the return type. Therefore preventing the need for having to define the method time and time again.